# Multiprocess python module seems to not work as expected for Spark MLlib when running in a Databricks cluster with 32 CPU cores

Tags: python, multithreading, apache-spark, multiprocessing, azure-databricks

Please note that due to the length of this post I advise you to look at the description of each function presented. This is because, the functions are executed successfully without any bug. I just present them for the reader to get a general view of the code executed. So pay more attention on my Theoretical part and My Question sections and not so much on the Technical section.

**[Theoretical part - Explain the situation]**

Initially, I would like to pinpoint that this is an execution-time related question. The code illustrated works perfectly, although the time execution is something I am concerned with.

I would like your opinion on a matter I have experienced the last few days working on **threading** and **multiprocessing** Python modules on a Databricks cluster with 32 CPU cores. Very briefly, I have created a function *(presented below)* which takes as input a Spark Dataframe and trains two SPARK MLlib classifiers. Prior to the training some extra cleaning and preparation is applied to the Spark Dataframe using again Spark alike commands. Both the time taken to train and preprocess each spark dataframe will be presented. This function, which includes the functions of training and preprocessing, is applied 15 times (aka to 15 different spark dataframes). Thus, you can understand that my goal in using *threading and multiprocessing* was to execute those 15 iterations at once and not sequentially (one after the other). Just only imagine that those 15 iterations will become 1500 in the near future. So, this is a benchmark of what is coming in terms of data scale up.

Before moving forward I would like to illustrate some of the conclusions I made while working on threading and multiprocessing. Based on this [article](https://medium.com/@bfortuner/python-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-73072ce5600b) by Brendan Fortuner, threading is mostly used for I/O bound tasks which are subject to GIL limitations (prevent two threads from executing simultaneously in the same program). On the opposite side, the multiprocessing module uses Processes to speed up Python operations that are CPU intensive because they benefit from multiple cores and avoid the GIL. Thus, even though I initially created a threading alike application that applies my function 15 times concurrently, I later changed to multiprocessing approach due to the reason written above.

**[Technical part]**

*The Spark dataframe*

```py
spark_df= pd.DataFrame({    'IMEI' : ['358639059721529', '358639059721529', '358639059721529', '358639059721529', '358639059721529', '358639059721735', '358639059721735', '358639059721735', '358639059721735', '358639059721735'],
                            'PoweredOn': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
                            'InnerSensorConnected': [1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0, 1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
                            'averageInnerTemperature': [2.5083397819149877, 12.76785419845581, 2.5431994716326396, 2.5875612214150556, 2.5786447594332143, 2.6642078435610212, 12.767857551574707, 12.767857551574707, 2.6131772499486625, 2.5172743565284166]
                            'OuterSensorConnected':[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
                            'OuterHumidity':[31.784826, 32.784826, 33.784826, 43.784826, 23.784826, 54.784826, 31.784826, 31.784826],
                            'EnergyConsumption': [70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0],
                            'DaysDeploymentDate': [10.0, 20.0, 21.0, 31.0, 41.0, 11.0, 19.0, 57.0, 44.0, 141.0],
                            'label': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]
                      }
                    )
spark_df= spark.createDataFrame(spark_df)
```

The dataframe is just presented to keep in mind the spark dataframe used. Imagine that those 10 rows is 7000 rows and the 2 IMEI are actually 15 unique IMEIs, because as I told you, I have 15 spark dataframes 1 per IMEI (['358639059721529', '358639059721735']).

*[The function applied]

```py
def training_models_operation_multiprocess(asset_id, location, asset_total_number, timestamp_snap, joined_spark_dataset):
 #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # KEYWORDS INITIALIZATION
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    device_length=int(asset_total_number)
    list_string_outputs=list()
    max_workers=16*2
    training_split_ratio=0.5
    testing_split_ratio=0.5
    cross_validation_rounds=2
    optimization_metric="ROC_AUC"
    features_column_name="features"
    disable_logging_value=1 # a value that prevents standard output to be logged at Application insights
    logger_initialization=instantiate_logger(instrumentation_key_value) #a logger instance

    # Time format
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # KEYWORDS INITIALIZED
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    try:

        print("{0}: START EXECUTION PLAN OF ASSET ID {1}: {2}/{3}".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format), asset_id, location, device_length))
        begin_time_0 = time.time()

        #1.1 Filter the rows related to the current asset
        begin_time_1 = time.time()

        filtered_dataset=joined_spark_dataset.where(joined_spark_dataset.IMEI.isin([asset_id]))
        filtered_dataset=apply_repartitioning(filtered_dataset, max_workers)

        end_time_1 = time.time() - begin_time_1
        list_string_outputs.append("{0}: FINISH Step 1.1 asset id {1}: {2}/{3} in: {4}\n".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format), asset_id, location, device_length, format_timespan(end_time_1)))

        #------------------------
        # FUNCTION: 1.2 Preprocess
        begin_time_2 = time.time()

        target_column_name=None
        target_column_name='label'
        preprocessed_spark_df=preprocess_data_pipeline(filtered_dataset, drop_columns_not_used_in_training, target_column_name, executor)
        preprocessed_spark_df=apply_repartitioning(preprocessed_spark_df, max_workers)

        end_time_2 = time.time() - begin_time_2
        list_string_outputs.append("{0}: FINISH Step 1.2 asset id {1}: {2}/{3} in: {4}\n".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format), asset_id, location, device_length, format_timespan(end_time_2)))

        #------------------------
        #FUNCTION: 1.3 Train-Test split
        begin_time_3 = time.time()

        target_column_name=None
        target_column_name='target'
        training_data, testing_data=spark_train_test_split(asset_id, preprocessed_spark_df, training_split_ratio, testing_split_ratio, target_column_name, disable_logging_value, logger_initialization)
        training_data=apply_repartitioning(training_data, max_workers)
        testing_data=apply_repartitioning(testing_data, max_workers)

        end_time_3 = time.time() - begin_time_3
        list_string_outputs.append("{0}: FINISH Step 1.3 asset id {1}: {2}/{3} in: {4}\n".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format), asset_id, location, device_length, format_timespan(end_time_3)))

        #FUNCTION: 1.4 Train the algorithms
        begin_time_4 = time.time()

        best_classifier_asset_id=spark_ml_classification(asset_id, cross_validation_rounds, training_data, testing_data, target_column_name, features_column_name, optimization_metric, disable_logging_value, 
                                                         logger_initialization)

        end_time_4 = time.time() - begin_time_4
        list_string_outputs.append("{0}: FINISH Step 1.4 asset id {1}: {2}/{3} in: {4}\n".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format), asset_id, location, device_length, format_timespan(end_time_4)))

        end_time_0 = time.time() - begin_time_0
        list_string_outputs.append("{0}: END EXECUTION PLAN OF ASSET ID {1}: {2}/{3} in: {4}\n".format(datetime.utcnow().strftime(date_format), asset_id, location, device_length, format_timespan(end_time_0)))

    except Exception as e:
            custom_logging_function(logger_initialization, disable_logging_value, "ERROR", "ERROR EXCEPTION captured in asset id {0}: {1}".format(asset_id, e))
            raise
    print(" ".join(list_string_outputs))
```

[FUNCTION 1.1]: Filter the dataset per IMEI
*Description: From the whole dataset with all the IMEI ids filter only the rows belonging to the IMEI per iteration number*

device_ids=['358639059721529', '358639059721735']
filtered_dataset=spark_df.where(spark_df.IMEI.isin([device_ids]))

[FUNCTION 1.2]: Preprocess Spark DF
*Description: Apply VectorAssembler to trainable features and StringIndexer to the label*

```py
   def preprocess_data_pipeline(spark_df, target_variable)
    stages = []

    # Convert label into label indices using the StringIndexer
    label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol=target_variable, outputCol="target").setHandleInvalid("keep") #target variable shoule be IntegerType
    stages += [label_stringIdx]

    numeric_columns=["PoweredOn", "InnerSensorConnected", "averageInnerTemperature", "OuterSensorConnected", "OuterHumidity", "EnergyConsumption", "DaysDeploymentDate"]

    # Vectorize trainable features
    assemblerInputs = numeric_columns
    assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, outputCol="features").setHandleInvalid("keep")
    stages += [assembler]

    partialPipeline = Pipeline().setStages(stages)
    pipelineModel = partialPipeline.fit(spark_df)
    preppedDataDF = pipelineModel.transform(spark_df)

    # Keep relevant columns
    selectedcols = ["target", "features"]
    dataset = preppedDataDF.select(selectedcols)
    dataset=dataset.drop(target_variable)

    #dataset.printSchema()
    return dataset
```

[FUNCTION 1.3: Train-Test split]
* Split the data to train and test spark df's using a Stratified kind of approach*

```py
def spark_train_test_split(device_id, prepared_spark_df, train_split_ratio, test_split_ratio, target_variable):

    trainingData = prepared_spark_df.sampleBy(target_variable, fractions={0: train_split_ratio, 1: train_split_ratio}, seed=10)
    testData = prepared_spark_df.subtract(trainingData)

    return trainingData, testData
```

[FUNCTION 1.4: Train the ML algorithms]
*Description: Train two classification algorithms and then select the one with the highest ROC_AUC score. Each classifier is trained using the CrossValidator class of Spark MLlib...For the first classifier (Random Forest) I cross validate 4 models while for the second classifier (Gradient Boosted Trees) I cross validate 8 models. To speed up things on this, I have set the parallelism parameter of the cross validator class equal to 8 (explanation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#model-selection-aka-hyperparameter-tuning))*

```py
def machine_learning_estimator_initialization(model_name, target_variable, features_variable):

    try:
        dictionary_best_metric={}
        dictionary_best_estimator={}
        list_of_classifiers=["RandomForest Classifier", "GradientBoost Classifier"]

        begin_time_train=time.time()
        for i in list_of_classifiers:

            pipeline_object, paramGrid, evaluator=machine_learning_estimator_initialization(i, target_column, features_column)

            start_time_classifier=time.time()

            # THE MOST TIME CONSUMING PART OF MY EXECUTION
            classification_object = CrossValidator(estimator=pipeline_object, estimatorParamMaps=paramGrid, evaluator=evaluator, numFolds=cross_validation_rounds, parallelism=8)

            classificationModel = classification_object.fit(training_dataset)
            end_time_classifier=time.time()-start_time_classifier
            print("Time passed to complete training for classifier {0} of asset id {1}: {2}".format(i, device_id, format_timespan(end_time_classifier)))

            predictions = classificationModel.transform(testing_dataset)
            evaluation_score_classifier=evaluator.evaluate(predictions, {evaluator.metricName: "areaUnderROC"})
            y_true = predictions.select([target_column]).collect()
            y_pred = predictions.select(['prediction']).collect()

            confusion_mat=confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
            confusion_table=pd.DataFrame(confusion_mat,
                                         columns=['0','1'],
                                         index=['0','1'])

            accuracy_value=accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred)
            f1_value=f1_score(y_true, y_pred, zero_division=1)
            precision_value=precision_score(y_true, y_pred, zero_division=1)
            recall_value=recall_score(y_true, y_pred, zero_division=1)
            hamming_loss_value=hamming_loss(y_true, y_pred)
            zero_one_loss_value=zero_one_loss(y_true, y_pred, normalize=False)

            list_of_metrics=['ROC_AUC', 'accuracy', 'f1', 'precision', 'recall', 'hamming_loss', 'zero_one_loss']
            list_of_metric_values=[evaluation_score_classifier, accuracy_value, f1_value, precision_value, recall_value, hamming_loss_value, zero_one_loss_value]

            evaluation_metric_name_index=list_of_metrics.index(evaluation_metric) # With this index I can locate any value selected for the evaluation metric

            if evaluation_metric=='ROC_AUC':
                dictionary_best_metric.update({"{0}_best_score".format(i): evaluation_score_classifier}) #alternative hamming_loss_value

            else:
                dictionary_best_metric.update({"{0}_best_score".format(i): list_of_metric_values[evaluation_metric_name_index]})

            dictionary_best_estimator.update({"{0}_best_estimator".format(i): classificationModel.bestModel})

        end_time_train=time.time()-begin_time_train
        print("Total time of training execution of two MLlib algorithms for the asset {0}: {1}".format(device_id, format_timespan(end_time_train)))

        maximum_metrics=['ROC_AUC', 'accuracy', 'f1', 'precision', 'recall']
        minimum_metrics=['hamming_loss', 'zero_one_loss']

        if evaluation_metric in maximum_metrics:
            index_of_best_model_score=list(dictionary_best_metric.keys()).index(max(dictionary_best_metric, key=dictionary_best_metric.get))

        else:
            index_of_best_model_score=list(dictionary_best_metric.keys()).index(min(dictionary_best_metric, key=dictionary_best_metric.get))

        classification_model_for_scoring=list(dictionary_best_estimator.values())[index_of_best_model_score]

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    return classification_model_for_scoring
```

The four functions presented above are those applied 15 times (15 spark dataframes, 1 per IMEI the unique id). For what I am concern is the time taken to execute those 15 iterations of the functions presented. As already said I have initially implemented an approach by following the threading module. The approach is as follows:

**[THREADING APPROACH]**

```py
import threading

#Creating a list of threads
device_ids=spark_df.select(sql_function.collect_set('IMEI').alias('unique_IMEIS')).collect()[0]['unique_IMEIS']
device_ids=device_ids[-15:]
location=range(1, len(device_ids)+1, 1)
devices_total_number=len(device_ids)

date_format = '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S'
timestamp_snapshot=datetime.utcnow()
timestamp_snap=timestamp_snapshot.strftime(date_format)

thread_list = list()

# #looping all objects, creating a thread for each element in the loop, and append them to thread_list
for location, i in enumerate(device_ids, 1):

    try:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=training_models_operation_multiprocess, args=(i, location, asset_total_number, timestamp_snap, spark_df,)
        thread_list.append(thread)
        thread.start()

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

**[BENCHMARK OF MULTIPROCESSING APPROACH]**


#--------------------------------------
# Wait for all threads to finish
for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()

print("Finished executing all threads")
```

**BENCHMARK: ON A CLUSTER WITH 32 CPU CORES: ~16m**

However, as already mentioned the treading is not used as my final approach. In the end, having read a couple of things about multiprocessing, I chose this approach.

**[MULTIPROCESSING APPROACH]**

```py
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from itertools import cycle

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()

    device_ids=datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled.select(sql_function.collect_set('IMEI').alias('unique_IMEIS')).collect()[0]['unique_IMEIS']
    device_ids=device_ids[-15:] #15 UNIQUE IMEI's 
    location=range(1, len(device_ids)+1, 1)
    devices_total_number=len(device_ids)

    pool_list=list()

    with Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
        start_time = time.time()
        tasks = [*zip(device_ids, location, cycle([str(devices_total_number)]), cycle([timestamp_snap]), cycle([datalake_spark_dataframe_downsampled]))]

        pool.starmap(training_models_operation_multiprocess,
                     iterable=(tasks),
                     chunksize=1)
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        pool.terminate()
        end_time = time.time()
        secs_per_iteration = (end_time - start_time) / len(device_ids)
        print("Time per iteration: {0}".format(format_timespan(secs_per_iteration)))
```

**[BENCHMARK ON A CLUSTER WITH 32 CPU cores]**

On average for every IMEI and its relevant spark df, RandomForest and GradientBoostedTrees took that time to execute: 5minutes and 6 minutes respectively.
[image]

Below you will notice the time take to execute each of the above 4 sub-fucntions (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4)
[image]

**[My Question]**

Having presented all the facts and results from my experiment it's time to write my question.

How is it possible with a cluster of 32 CPU cores (2 workers with 16 cores each) to get such a time consuming result? Is it possible a Pool execution to take almost 12 minutes to run a cross validation on a dataframe with approximately 467 rows... My spark df had 7,000 rows in total and with 15 ids I get 467 rows per IMEI id. In my humble mind 32 CPU cores are great computational power, yet they execute a sequence of functions in 15 minutes.

Thus, I want to understand why is this happening:

Is it a problem of Spark? Meaning, that it cannot allocate properly 32 CPU cores to execute 4 simple functions? Combining the Multiprocessing module I would expect 15 iterations to complete in much less time. Maybe it's something that I have not yet understood about multiprocessing and my execution can only achieve up to this execution time.

I would really appreciate your opinion on this matter, because maybe I miss the point of multiprocessing. I cannot digest the fact that I have 32 cpu cores and my execution takes 1 minute, per Pool, for Spark to complete it. Please, don't take into consideration the fact that I use Spark to train data of 500 rows dataframe because in the near future this df will have 100,000 rows and more. So I have in mind the disadvantages of Spark over Python on such small number of rows. But it's the multiprocessing approach I want to understand more.

Comment: what are you setting your "spark.scheduler.mode" as? FIFO or FAIR? (FIFO is default)

Comment: @murtihash FAIR...I don't change this value from the SparkContext, although my Spark UI writes FAIR (I well remember that)

Comment: @murtihash shall I change my Scheduler mode from FAIR to FIFO?

Comment: with threading/concurrent futures , FAIR is the way to go

Comment: @murtihash Ok it's actually one of the options I have already implemented....But I will also check with FIFO scheduler since you mentioned it :)

Comment: @murtihash my only concern about threading is that its used mainly for I/O bound tasks and the one I execute is not an I/O...In any case I appreciate your suggestions and inputs.

Comment: @ShubhamJain I would really appreciate your thoughts on this question!

Comment: @RohitNimmala  I would really appreciate your thoughts on this question!

Comment: @tdelaney I would really appreciate your thoughts on this question!